# Random error message that causes restart of computer

Tags: 15.10, 64-bit, suspend, lenovo, restart

Every now and again, my computer screen goes black and I get an error message (in terminal font) that says,

> Warning!!!
>
> Boot script table is modified!!!
>     Please contact your vendor.

It displays for a few seconds and then reboots the entire computer.

It doesn't seem to happen after only a single situation, so as far as I'm concerned it's random.

Sometimes it happens when I open my laptop lid to take it out of suspend mode; other times it just happens out of the blue.

This only started happening after I installed Ubuntu. My computer was originally preinstalled with Windows 10 Home 64-Bit, but I then wiped the Windows partition & installed Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 64-Bit. Happened on that one. Then, just yesterday I got fed up with the absurd bugginess of 14.04 and switched to what I have now: Ubuntu 15.10 (which, by the way, works comparatively beautiful).

I keep having my work being interrupted if not ruined, and this would be so much worse if I didn't have auto-save and auto-backup enabled in Gedit, LibreOffice, etc.

What's going on?

---

**Note**: Before installing, when I first booted to USB, I selected "Check disk for defects" and it found none. Just wanted to add that really quckly; not sure if it's relevant, but eh.

---

#### Stats

- *Make & Model*: Lenovo G50-45
- *Operating Systems*:

  - *Original (Not Installed)*: Windows 10 Home 64-Bit
  - *Previous (Not Installed)*: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 64-Bit
  - *Current*: Ubuntu 15.10 64-Bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little research, I have learned that this is a problem specific to some Lenovo laptops. In fact, it seems pretty specific to your model.

These laptops have something special built into the firmware that verifies EFI boot files, and makes sure they are valid and not dangerous. This works fine with Windows, but the problem arises when you install Linux.

Someone discovered a vulnerability in this protection script:

> Certain firmware implementations may not correctly protect memory that stores the BIOS S3 Boot Script when a system is suspended.  Exploitation of such vulnerabilities could potentially lead to bypass security features and/or denial of service the platform.

Your laptop is on the affected list. If you installed [this BIOS update](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/g40-45-notebook-lenovo/downloads/DS100823), then it might be the reason for your problem. That is meant to be the fix for the vulnerability, and it seems to cause issues with Linux.

Supposedly, the problem occurs only when waking from suspend, and unfortunately, there seems to be no fix. Your best option is to just avoid sleep mode, or reinstall Windows and have a dual-boot. You could modify the BIOS firmware ad re-flash, but I doubt you want to do that.

More details:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=212044

Comment: Goddamn Lenovo...

Comment: And yeah, this sucks. Well I don't remember if I installed any BIOS update; if I did, it probably was an automatic thing (hooray for Windows 10 automatic updates, eh?). I know it had installed a number of updates, I can tell you that much.

Comment: Also, I would love to reinstall Windows (and possibly dual-boot), but I can't. I have the ISO and a bootable flash drive set up for Windows 10 Home but unfortunately I can't access the product key since apparently it was included in the BIOS, which according to Lenovo Support was wiped along with the Windows partition. (I didn't dual-boot initially. I know... I feel *so* stupid. x.x )

Comment: @SarahofGaia The product key will be automatically detected when you install Windows 10. The key is not erased when you format the BIOS. In fact, even if it was, you'd be fine. MS stores your hardware info online and uses it to auto activate your Windows install, even if you did an upgrade from 7 or 8.1

Comment: You mean Lenovo Support lied to me? Ugh, dirty... I guess it's no surprise that 15 seconds later when I asked what I could do they mentioned that I could pay $69 for Lenovo's premium support package... -_-

Comment: Lenovo is officially on my shitlist.

Comment: Also, I didn't do an upgrade from 7 or 8.1, though. Windows 10 was preinstalled. Will that change anything?

Comment: It shouldn't Windows maintained the key-in-BIOS feature, and 10 added the automatic online activation. You should be fine.

Comment: So what you're saying is that wiping the Windows partition during the installation of Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS did not wipe out the Windows 10 product key stored in the BIOS/motherboard/whatever?

Comment: Nope. If it did, then something is seriously wrong with your computer. Computers that ship with Windows 8+ have the product key in the BIOS firmware. Wiping the hard drive does not wipe the BIOS.

Comment: Lenovo Support is most likely still using old knowledge. If your laptop doesn't have a sticker on the outside with a product key, and it came with Windows 8 or later, the key is almost definitely in the BIOS firmware, and can even be retrieved by using something such as Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder.

Comment: I see, and I'll be able to use Windows 10 long enough without the product key in order to install Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder in order to find the product key?

Comment: Unless it's been changed in the past few weeks. It should actually happen automatically during the install

Comment: @SarahofGaia No problem. Just a quick (sellout) question: would you mind marking this answer as accepted?

Comment: I don't mind at all. ^_^ I'm just glad it wasn't my fault with something I did during installing Ubuntu. Lol. I tried following the directions to the "T". Lol.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an unproven assumption that this is specific to some Lenovo devices: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=212044

> Postby syeager » Mon Jun 13, 2016 2:27 am
>
> I have been installing different linux distros on my HP Envy and all
>   have the same problem: sleep once, fine; sleep again, and it will not
>   recover with a black screen, where upon on reboot (the only option
>   with a hardware reboot) i get the error message 'boot script table
>   modified'. Not only does this happen to linux distros, i have had it
>   happen to windows 10 clean install. I just installed windows 10 to an
>   ssd and added bodhi linux as a uefi boot. Just put windows to sleep
>   (for the first time after rebooting) after playing an old XP game
>   (Neverwinter Nights) and it gave the same problem. Does that help you
>   analyze it? I can test theories, if anyone has one.
>
> OK, i tried ubuntu, thinking that i heard they paid microsoft for
>   uefi, so maybe it would handle awaking from sleep better. No it
>   doesn't. Then i tried robolinux, which is a debian release but also
>   booted up with the cd with a legacy boot instead of uefi booting from
>   the cd, and it can sleep just fine. i am assuming it is the legacy
>   boot. Thoughts?